# What is the difference between てある and the passive (ら)れる?

Tags: grammar

For example:

"昼ごはんは作ってある" and "昼ごはんは作られた". Don't both mean the lunch has been made?

As a second question, what would be the difference between 昼ごはんは作ってある and 昼ごはんは作ってあった?

Much appreciated

Comment: I feel like I answered the same question just recently.

Comment: And God said, "let there be lunch", and 昼ごはんは作られた...

Comment: @l'électeur これですね・・・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41028/how-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F-differs/41222#41222

Comment: @brokenheadphones まさかの自発の「らる」で笑ってしまいました

Answer (score 1):

昼ごはんは作ってある => The lunch has been made.

昼ごはんは作られた => The lunch was made.

昼ごはんは作ってあった? => The lunch had been made.

Answer (score 0):

> "昼ごはんは作ってある" and "昼ごはんは作られた". Don't both mean the lunch has been made?

Yes. They both mean the lunch has been made but we would never say "昼ごはんは作られた".

"昼ごはんは作ってある" means "There has been a lunch". "昼ごはんは作ってあった" means "There had been a lunch".

Answer (score -1):

> Don't both mean the lunch has been made?

*Yes*. 昼ごはんは作ってある means "I made a lunch". 昼ごはんは作られた means "a lunch is made", but 昼ごはんは作られた is bit odd…