# Japanese grammar "てある”

Tags: grammar, aspect

So I just encountered the grammar "te aru" and according to Japanesetest4you it means that *something has been done*. They provide the following sentence as an example:

> 君の靴下も全部洗濯**してある**。
>   *Kimi no kutsushita mo zenbu sentaku **shite aru**.*
>   'All your socks have also been washed.'

Would it be wrong of me to just say:

> 君の靴下も全部洗濯**した**。
>   *Kimi no kutsushita mo zenbu sentaku **shita**.*

Would there be a big difference in meaning?

Comment: There is a difference. Whether you would consider it big or small might be subjective. Can we see your translation of the second sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41028/how-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-and-%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8a%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f-differs/41222#41222

Answer (score 2):

The difference is like the difference between "they have been washed" and "(someone) washed them".

> 君{きみ}の靴下{くつした}も全部{ぜんぶ}**洗濯{せんたく}してある**

- All of your socks **have** also **been washed**
- Your socks **have** all **been washed** as well

> 君の靴下も全部**洗濯した**

- **(I have) washed** all of your socks as well
- **(She has) washed** all of your socks as well
- **(He has) washed all** of your socks as well