# 女：アンケート用紙は、いつ配るんですか。 男：最初からプログラムにはさんであります。

Tags: meaning

> 女：アンケート用紙は、いつ配るんですか。
> 男：最初からプログラムにはさんであります。

Can someone explain what the さんであります means, from the dictionary it says in between a sandwich, which does not make sense here.

Comment: You're probably misthinking what "プログラム" means here: it means, in this context, some kind of documents.

Comment: 挟んであります... 挟む{はさむ}

Comment: Just a note on question titles. It helps people search for similar questions if the title references the thing you want to know, as opposed to just being the text you are looking at with no context.

Answer (score 2):

This は is not a particle but a part of the verb 挟む ("to insert; to put between").

- **プログラム**: "(event) program" (leaflet)
- **に**: destination marker (particle)
- **挟んで【はさんで】**: te-form of 挟む
- **あります**: expresses something has been done in advance

  - [Stative verbs: ～ている　vs　～てある　vs　～（ら）れる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5505/5010)
  - [How ~てある and ~ておいた differs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41028/5010)

> 最初からプログラムにはさんであります。
>
> I have inserted it in your program (leaflet) from the beginning.
> It's already inserted in your program.